# Laravel to Laravel User Authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I have two laravel project. I want to Authenticate both of them by API. Means if someone have account with one laravel project he can login another one.Is there any tutorial which i can follow

Comment: **if someone have account with one laravel project he can login another one** use single DB or clone DB or use remote DB

Comment: Why do you use same db for both projects?

Comment: both are different project and in different place so can't use the same DB. Is there any thing can do with API or any tutorial

Comment: For Authentication alone, you can use the same DB, for other functionalities you can use another DB (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#using-multiple-database-connections)